# How to convert a SQL query to a Laravel DB query?

Tags: database, laravel

I have an SQL query.

```
SELECT
    nguyenlieu.manguyenlieu,
    nguyenlieu.tennguyenlieu,
    SUM(chitietnhapmua.soluong) AS slsum
FROM chitietnhapmua
JOIN nguyenlieu
    ON  nguyenlieu.manguyenlieu = chitietnhapmua.manguyenlieu
JOIN
(SELECT nhapmua.* FROM nhapmua WHERE nhapmua.trangthai = 1) AS nhapmua
    ON nhapmua.maphieunhap = chitietnhapmua.maphieunhap
GROUP BY nguyenlieu.manguyenlieu
```

It run on the SQL. I have to try

```
$data = DB::table('nguyenlieu')
    ->join('chitietnhapmua','nguyenlieu.manguyenlieu','=','chitietnhapmua.manguyenlieu')
          ->join('nhapmua',function($join){
              $join->on('nhapmua.maphieu','=','chitietnhapmua.maphieu')
                  ->where('nhapmua.trangthai','=','1');
          })
          ->select('nhapmua.maphieunhap','nguyenlieu.manguyenlieu','nguyenlieu.tennguyenlieu','chitietnhapmua.soluong')
          ->get();
```

but I can't to translate to Laravel framework using class DB.

Comment: What problem are you encountering specifically? "Can't do it" is rather a vague problem description.

Comment: I want to use SQL query on laravel framework. I have try to use DB class but not get the respond. Please help me to translate the SQL query to laravel framework code. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that much is clear, but "do it for me" does not really make a good question. What SQL does your present PHP code above create? What is different between that and what you want?

Comment: SQL query work on phpmyadmin and respond results. But I want to use methods provided by  DB class on laravel framework. I have to try this by code above but get errors. Please help me.